# How can we print the strings using printf

Tags: c

```
   char a[3]="26";
   char i[25]="/sys/class/gpio/gipo";
   char *j=strcat(i,a);
   printf("i=",i);
   printf("\nj=",j);
```

The output of the program is,

```
   i=
   j=
```

Comment: `printf` won't print any of the arguments unless you tell it to. You want `printf("i=%s\n");` and `printf("j=%s\n");`.

Comment: See chapter 1 of your beginner-level C programming book. Go go go!

Comment: Lundin thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
printf("i=%s",i);
```

To print out the contents of i, and the same thing for j (but obviously substituting 'j' for 'i'). Without these format specifiers, the code will not work.